# Response from Php File to Ajax is not getting sent

Tags: plugins, php, ajax

I am trying to send some response from Php script to Ajax, but it is not getting sent.Below is my code.

For now I am sending dummy data which I will change later..

Php Script..

```
        $response = ['Successfull callback','ndnvnvnsobdboi','ijjijbujbhu'];
       
        echo json_encode($response);
        
        die();
```

Ajax Script...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("#login_otp_btn").click(function(event){
    val();
  event.preventDefault();
  jQuery.ajax({
            url: wpac_ajax_url.ajax_url,
            type:'POST',
            data :{
                dataType:'JSON',
                action : 'login_ajax_callback',
                login : $("#login_mobile").val(),
                
               success:function(response){
                    console.log("url wpac " + wpac_ajax_url.ajax_url); 
                    if(!response == ""){
                    response = JSON.parse( response );
                    console.log(response);
                    }else{
                        console.log("Response is empty");
                         }
                    },
                    });
                    $("#login_otp_field").show();   
                    })
                });
```

I am getting Response is empty in my Console window. Which is in else statement

Comment: What's wpac_ajax_url.ajax_url? Is it the admin_ajax.php endpoint? Are you registering the action handler with both wp_ajax_ and wp_ajax_nopriv_ ? Can you verify if your handler is actually being called, e.g. by tracing out with an error_log? And can you check the network tab in your debug tools to make sure the request is completing with 200 OK?

Comment: Your problem is in this line: 
`if(!response == ""){`
the ! sign is not at the correct place, i.e:
 `if(response != ""){`

Comment: Issue Solved.....I was missing the closing brace for   data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue Solved I was missing a closing brace for data...

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#login_otp_btn").click(function(event){
    val();
    event.preventDefault();
 jQuery.ajax({
        url: wpac_ajax_url.ajax_url,
        type:'POST',
        data :{
            dataType:'JSON',
            action : 'login_ajax_callback',
            login : $("#login_mobile").val(),
            }

           success:function(response){
                console.log("url wpac " + wpac_ajax_url.ajax_url); 
                if(response !== ""){
                response = JSON.parse( response );
                console.log(response);
                }else{
                    console.log("Response is empty");
                     }
                },
                });
                $("#login_otp_field").show();   
                })
            });
```

Comment: `if(!response == ""){` is still incorrect.